# How to get img tag to fit to scale inside a css grid cell without object-fit?

Tags: html, css, vue.js

This is a vue component, its parent renders 8 of these components in a 2 x 4 even layout. The image is larger than its grid container. I would like it to shrink to fit the container while maintaining its aspect ratio. However object-fit is having no effect on the img tag and the image is rendered full size, drastically warping the grid and messing up my layout.

When the img tag is commented out, its parent div formats to the correct size and fills its grid container.

```
<template>
    <div class="camera-wrapper">
        <img class="camera" src="../assets/tsLogo.png" />
    </div>
</template>


<style scoped>
.camera-wrapper {
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}

.camera {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Are you using a css framework like bootstrap? Try putting the class of "img-responsive" on it?

Comment: no not using bootstrap. not going to import it either as its too bloated and not scoped

Answer (score 1):

Would swapping to background-image on the div and using background-size: contain be possible instead of an img element?

I am sorry I cannot put up a snippet as I’m confined to a touch device at the moment

Comment: That is what i have opted for in the end yeah. thanks